# Выборка элементов по значению атрибута

Tags: javascript, dom

Мне нужно захватить в переменную атрибут с каким-либо значением. В jQuery это сделать легко, но как это делается на чистом JS?

Мне нужно захватить атрибут, который имеет значение 1.jpg

```
<img src="1.jpg" alt="1jpg">
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` позволяет использовать селекторы аналогичные селекторам в CSS

Answer (score 5):

можете использовать функции [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) и [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelector('img[src="1.jpg"]')
```

Пример:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += document.querySelector('img[src="1.jpg"]').getAttribute('alt');
```

```html
<img src="1.jpg" alt="1jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Если это у вас один элемент `img`, то вы можете написать

```
var scr = document.images[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Иначе вам надо как-то его идентифицировать, например, при помощи атрибута `id`.